# WebView2 can't load client certificate

Tags: authentication, https, certificate, mutex, webview2

folks, I am writing a c# WPF program using WebView2 to access a inner website which requires mutual SSL authentication. I holds a valid client certificate. But I am stuck in how to let webview2  render this certificate to server. After a bit digging via search engine and having a talk with ChatGPT I got two approaches: the one is using addtional arguments,like this:

```
 CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions ops = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions()
 {
   AdditionalBrowserArguments = " --ignore-certificate-errors  "
      + " --auto-select-client-certificate-for-urls=https://test.com"
      + $" --client-certificate={crt2.Thumbprint}"
 };
 CoreWebView2Environment env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, null, ops);
 await webview.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
```

I have done all things without receving any exceptions. however, it yet failed. WebView2 didn't provide the cert to server.

Another way I haved digged out is, like below, using ClientCertificateRequested event and select the certificate from MutuallyTrustedCertificates. But, No matter where I installed/import the client certificate, the list MutuallyTrustedCertificates is alway empty.

```
private void CoreWebView2_ClientCertificateRequested(object sender, 

Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2ClientCertificateRequestedEventArgs e)
{
   IReadOnlyList<CoreWebView2ClientCertificate> certificateList = e.MutuallyTrustedCertificates;
   if (certificateList.Count() > 0)
   {
      // There is no significance to the order, picking a certificate arbitrarily.
      e.SelectedCertificate = certificateList.LastOrDefault();
      // Continue with the selected certificate to respond to the server.
      e.Handled = true;
   }
   else
   {
     // Continue without a certificate to respond to the server if certificate list is 

empty.
          e.Handled = true;
       }
   }
```

Aditionally, I have verified the client certificate and server logical using a tiny node.js test project.
Now I have no idea about how to resolve the problem of submitting client certificate to server via WebView2. I need your help.